# adb is automatically connected by the remote device，but I did not use adb connect

Tags: adb, android-studio-3.6

when I updated Android Studio to 3.6.1 adb is automatically connected by the remote device，**but I did not use adb connect**。These devices are under the same wifi。How can I solve this problem？

Comment: I created an issue and got the solution.
On linux/mac:

adb kill-server && ADB_MDNS=0 adb start-server

On windows:

cmd /C "set ADB_MDNS=0 && adb kill-server && adb start-server"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the latest version of Android Studio 3.6. A couple of my colleagues seem to have the same problem where any adb-over-wifi devices are discovered automatically and added to the device list in adb.

I could not find anything about this in the changelogs for the IDE or the platform tools, nor could I find a setting to turn this discovery off. I suggest you create an issue on the bugtracker.

@Nemoyang commented that you can disable this behavior by setting an environment variable `ADB_MDNS` to 0. It seems Google is working on an improved adb over wifi through mDNS, but hasn't really disclosed any information.

Comment: On linux/mac:

adb kill-server && ADB_MDNS=0 adb start-server

On windows:

cmd /C "set ADB_MDNS=0 && adb kill-server && adb start-server"

Comment: Created a IssueTracker ticket for this.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161244414

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your devices , the WIFI-debug mode will be disable. If it still connect again and you are using android device, going to develop and turn of this.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that these devices are not mine,will connect to my computer in just a wifi network,I can't turn off someone else's device.The weird thing is why the computer does not have adb connect, the device can actively connect to the computer

Comment: oh i see, try this command `adb disconnect` and check again `adb devices`

Comment: That doesn't work, disconnect is only temporary, and will be connected automatically after a while.And I tried to kill adb server and restart,doesn't work.